# Accessing / executing generic methods via reflection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I'm trying to dynamically switch out my table annotations' schema values @ Runtime when using EF6.

So here's what I've got thus far:

```
var builder = new DbModelBuilder()
var dbSetProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>));

foreach (PropertyInfo property in dbSetProperties)
{
    Type[] propTypes = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();

    // Iterate the DbSets and set the correct schema
    foreach (Type dbSetType in propTypes)
    {
        // Get the TableAttribute
        var tableAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(dbSetType, typeof(TableAttribute));

        MethodInfo dbModelMethodInfo = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
        MethodInfo entityTypeConfigMethodInfo = typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>).GetMethod("ToTable", new[] { typeof(String), typeof(String) });
        MethodInfo genericDbModelMethodInfo = dbModelMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(dbSetType);

        genericDbModelMethodInfo.Invoke(builder, null);
        entityTypeConfigMethodInfo.Invoke(genericDbModelMethodInfo, new Object[] { (tableAttribute as TableAttribute).Name, "NEW_SCHEMA_VALUE" });
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this (which doesn't work):

```
builder.Entity<dbSetType>().ToTable((tableAttribute as TableAttribute).Name, "NEW_SCHEMA_VALUE");
```

Basically, for T I want to pull the DbSets, determine the Class used in the Entity<> generic, get the TableAttribute, and set the Schema to a new value.

Currently, on entityTypeConfigMethodInfo.Invoke, I'm getting an error of "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true".

What am I missing?

Comment: `Invoke(genericDbModelMethodInfo` makes no sense

Comment: I get the same error with Invoke(builder -- that was my first stab at this :)

Comment: How is dbSetType defined?

Comment: I totally forgot the inner loop - updated OP to reflect (ha ha)

Comment: This is because it is still an open generic, you retrieved the method for an open generic type. You cannot invoke this. You must get the method for a *specific* type, so you need something like `MethodInfo entityTypeConfigMethodInfo = typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string)).GetMethod(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right closed generic methodinfo for the second call you rewrite your code to:

```
MethodInfo genericDbModelMethodInfo = dbModelMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(dbSetType);
MethodInfo entityTypeConfigMethodInfo = genericDbModelMethodInfo.ReturnType.GetMethod("ToTable", new[] { typeof(String), typeof(String) });
```

Then you have to use the return value of the `genericDbModelMethodInfo.Invoke` call as the first parameter in the second call.

```
var obj = genericDbModelMethodInfo.Invoke(builder, null);
entityTypeConfigMethodInfo.Invoke(obj, new Object[] { (tableAttribute as TableAttribute).Name, "NEW_SCHEMA_VALUE" });
```

That is because the first parameter in `MethodInfo.Invoke` is the object you want to invoke the method on.

Comment: Ah!  That does it - so when chaining methods via reflection, I need to use the previous object in the following invoke?

Comment: Yes `MethodInfo` objects are just information about a particular method in regards to Metadata. These information are not tied to an object, so you have to provide it, if wanted (non static method). Did you get it to work as expected?

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, what did you expect?

You say you get the error on this line:

```
entityTypeConfigMethodInfo.Invoke(genericDbModelMethodInfo, new Object[] { (tableAttribute as TableAttribute).Name, "NEW_SCHEMA_VALUE" });
```

The problem is not with this line, but with this line:

```
MethodInfo entityTypeConfigMethodInfo = typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>).GetMethod("ToTable", new[] { typeof(String), typeof(String) });
```

You're getting the method `ToTable` of *which* type?

The type containing that method is still an open generic type. You must specify the type arguments to make it a specific type, then you can get the method to invoke.

In other words, you need this:

```
MethodInfo entityTypeConfigMethodInfo =
    typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>).MakeGenericType(...).GetMethod("ToTable", new[] { typeof(String), typeof(String) });
                                     ^-------------------^
```

Comment: That makes sense - ok, that definitely more closely matches what I had expected in my 'I want this, but it doesn't work' example.  Now how would I go about Invoking that against the builder object?

Answer (score 0):

Since EntityTypeConfiguration is a generic Type , could you specify the type of Generic parameter being used in your object for **EntityTypeConfiguration**. 
Ex :

```
 Type type= typeof (GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
```

Here 'GenericClass' is a generic class with generic 'T' parameter. 
   I have specified **int type** while getting the type information of it. 
Then Invoke the method on this type will work fine.

I have written a sample code which does the same, but minimally what  you are trying to do and may help you solve your error.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Type type= typeof (GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int));

        var method = type.GetMethod("TestMethod");

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);


        method.Invoke(instance, null); 

    }
}

public class GenericClass<T> where T : struct // These parameters can be anything
{
    public T TestMethod()
    {
        T a = new T();

        return a; 
    }
}
```